# Ubuntu 14.04 Remote shutdown teamviewer or php script

Tags: scripts, shutdown, php, services, teamviewer

when I try to remotely shutdown with teamviewer my Ubuntu 14:04 pc turns off uncompletely because of the teamviewer team advice appear on the desktop (wine supported).
I solved by running the coomand shutdown -HP 5 and next stopping the daemon teamviewer (this is complicated from a smartphone).
Does anyone have a simpler solution? Maybe a php script to integrate into an html page accessible from the web?
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with Guacamole (http://guac-dev.org). With a php script it could be dangerous and with teamviewer it freezes because every time I have to stop the demon with "teamviewer --daemon stop" from a remote terminal (very complicated if you connect from a mobile).

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this from a PHP script. Shutting down your PC accessible from the web sounds like a really bad idea.

I myself would make a shell script, and execute it when needed. For example this script would be saved on the desktop:

```
#!/bin/sh
shutdown -HP 1
```

And if you run it, this shuts down the computer in one minute.

Comment: In ubuntu 14.04 the option -t is not recognized, so i tried shutdown -HP 1 but without closing the teamviewer connection (the advice message doesn't appear) and it works.
With a php script it will be safety hiding it..

Comment: I updated my answer to use `-HP`

Comment: With HP option it takes 60 minutes, it's better 1